# How can I block a user form writng to a read write smart card in Symantec App control or other means?

Tags: smartcard

How to prevent a user from writing to a smart card and taking info with him on the card?  If smart card is read write what can prevent them from writing to the free space on the card?

Comment: You should definitely attempt to acquire the most basic information yourself before asking here. Try to add details to your question to avoid further downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for assuming I had not tried to gather any basic information.  I asked the question to help me understand what it is I need to consider in uncovering the possibilities.  Downvote to your response since the whole point here is to help others.

Comment: feel free to add your dead ends to the question to clarify what exactly you want to know.

Comment: @cl7 You really should tell more about your scenario. My crystal ball shows sort of restricted computer system where users are physically checked not to carry any memory device to prevent data exfiltration. But they are allowed to take smart cards as they need it for two-factor authentication. And you need to ensure that they can't write any sensitive data to the card? Okay, probably not....good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even the dumbest memory card, which can always be read, allows writing only after PIN presentation.

Modern smart cards have very fine granular sophisticated access rules for the file system, which may require different forms of authentications for every file.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The way I understand it (while it may not be correct) is that access to the any files after PIN authentication would need to be administered though the application software such as Microsoft Identity Management (MIM).  For example could write access to the file free space be blocked for any application except for Authentication only so nothing else could be written to the card's free space?

Comment: Typically a smart card has a complete security scheme and is locked tight before it arrives in the hands of the intended card holder so Create File would definitely need an authentication or more likely than not a cryptographic one instead of a simple PIN. Anything else would surprise me. Do you have details concerning your card?